# Insert only new properties into embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to insert new values into an embedded document *only if the embedded document doesn't already have the key*. For example, my document is initially

```
{
    name: "doc1",
    embeddedDoc: {
        a: 123,
        b: 456
    }
}
```

Then if I were to "insert" `{b: 789, c: 101}`, I want the result to have `embeddedDoc: {a: 123, b: 456, c: 101}` (insert the new `c`, don't touch the existing `b`). Is there a way to do this?

The best solution I have so far is to run one query per element in the inserting object:

```
collection.update(
    {"embeddedDoc.b": {$exists: false}},
    {$set: {"embeddedDoc.b": 456}}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would not have an object in my document but an array instead. It won't solve the issue of not overwrting data by itself, but it does turn the "lookup" on a "key" into using "data" that can be indexed. This is going to make a "big" difference if you intend these kinds of updates regularly.

```js
{
    "name": "Doc1",
    "properties": [
        { "key": "a", "value": 123 },
        { "key": "b", "value": 456 }
    ]
}
```

So with new data for "b" and "c", then you could make a query attempt like this:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { "properties.key" { "$nin": [ "b", "c" ]  } },
    { 
        "$push": { 
            "properties": { 
                "$each": [
                    { "key": "b", "value": 789 },
                    { "key": "c", "value": 101 }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "multi": true }
)
```

As said, at least than "can" use an index which a "key" lookup with [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) cannot, and you can at least "try" to do this operation as a "first shot", where if documents did meet the given condition where both "b" and "c", "key" values are not present then those documents would be affected.

The fallback case would of course be to try individually for each property here, but the whole process is really not hard to work out with [Bulk Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/):

```js
var obj = { "b": 456, "c": 101 };

var keys = Object.keys(obj),
    mapped = keys.map(function(key) {
        return { "key": key, "value": obj[key] };
    });

var bulk = intitializeOrderedBulkOp();

bulk.find({ "properties.key": { "$nin": keys } }).update({
    "$push": { "properties": { "$each": mapped } }
});

keys.forEach(function(key) {
    bulk.find({ "properties.key": { "$ne": key } }).update({
        "$push": { "properties": { "key": key, "value": obj[key] } }
    });
});

bulk.execute();
```

Noting that if the first query did actually succeed, then everything else might well be a "no-op". But if you are doing this with "multi" as this does, then you never really can be sure unless you already know how many documents to test for. So probably sending all at once is *"better safe than sorry"*.

So it's nice an simple to code, makes one trip to and from the server due to bulk operations, and is "efficient" in the lookup of data to match conditions due to the ability to use an index.

The "discarding merge" logic you want to implement will always mean multiple updates. But if you at least make the process as "efficient" as possible, then that is at least one less thing to worry about.

Comment: I had to change to a key/value array as you suggested for other reasons and just got to trying this out. I don't think your update query works because, with your example, the predicate `$nin: ["b", "c"]` doesn't match the document with keys `["a", "b"]`, and the `$push` would add duplicates if it did match. Would need something like `$addToSet` with a specifiable key.

Comment: @ZachB Please read carefully as the term use there is "attempt", which means it only might work where both were not present and when it does not then you fall back to the other operations. This is really about the bulk operations here and not the guarantee that a first attempt to put everything in at once is going to always work.

Comment: Oh oh, I see now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that you can do better than 2 queries for many properties. If you have many properties, you can make the first query to get all the properties, then knowing the properties you have, find the missing one as set difference. Then update only missing properties.

So for the arbitrary number of properties, you end up with 2 queries and a simple application logic. Note that in highly busy application something can happen between query1(find) and query2(update).

Comment: Thanks. I omitted from my question that I'm potentially updating multiple docs (typically 1 to 5), so query1(find) and query2(update) would have to be done for each doc. Typical number of properties in the insert doc is 10 to 50, so two queries per doc still wins, although it's more code.